# Arrange Toric Surfaces on top of each other

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

How can I have these two surfaces on top of each other in the y-plane. I tried with this code but it didn't work.Can someone offer ideas?I have tried several ways but they all couldn't work

```
Cx=1/80;
Cy=1/70;
M=6;
Dr=20;

n=2^(M-1);
Vertex=[0 0 0];
phi = (linspace(-pi,pi,n));
r=(linspace(0,Dr,n))';

x = -r*cos(phi)+Vertex(1);

y = -r*sin(phi)+Vertex(2);

z=(Cx*x.^2+Cy*y.^2)./(1+(1-sqrt(Cx*x.^2+Cy*y.^2).^2)./(x.^2+y.^2))+Vertex(3);

surf(z,x,y)
axis
set(gca, 'YDir','reverse');    
xlabel('X-axis','fontweight','bold');
ylabel('Z-axis','fontweight','bold');
zlabel('Y-axis','fontweight','bold');
hold on
Vertex=[pi pi pi];
phi = (linspace(-pi,pi,n));
r=(linspace(0,Dr,n))';

x = -r*cos(phi)+Vertex(1);

y = -r*sin(phi)+Vertex(2);

z=(Cx*x.^2+Cy*y.^2)./(1+(1-sqrt(Cx*x.^2+Cy*y.^2).^2)./(x.^2+y.^2))+Vertex(3);

surf(z,x,y)
axis 
set(gca, 'YDir','reverse');    
xlabel('X-axis','fontweight','bold');
ylabel('Z-axis','fontweight','bold');
zlabel('Y-axis','fontweight','bold');
```

**EDIT**:

The idea is to produce something similar to this:

```
M=5;
n=2^(M-1);
c=1/20;
Dr=1/10;
k=-1;
Vertex=[0 0 0];

phi = (linspace(0,2*pi,n));
r=(linspace(0,Dr,n))';

x = r*cos(phi)+Vertex(1);
y = r*sin(phi)+Vertex(2);
z = (c*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2))./ ...
    (1+sqrt(1-(1+k)*c^2*((r*cos(phi)).^2+ ...
    (r*sin(phi)).^2)))+Vertex(3);

surf(x,z,y);

set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'ZBuffer')
hold on
Vertex=[0 0.399 0];

phi = (linspace(0,2*pi,n));
r=(linspace(0,Dr,n))';

x = r*cos(phi)+Vertex(1);
y = r*sin(phi)+Vertex(2);
z = (c*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2))./ ...
    (1+sqrt(1-(1+k)*c^2*((r*cos(phi)).^2+ ...
    (r*sin(phi)).^2)))+Vertex(3);

surf(x,z,y)
```

Comment: Can you clarify "*on top of each other in the y-plane*", please? What portion do you want to align? Do you have an example figure to which you could link?

Comment: Yes, we couldn't understand if the problem is the stack order or how to adjust the formula so that the toroids are located one higher the other in the Y axis.

Comment: The idea is to produce something similar to thisM=5;n=2^(M-1);c=1/20; Dr=1/10;k=-1;Vertex=[0 0 0];phi = (linspace(0,2*pi,n));r=(linspace(0,Dr,n))';x = r*cos(phi)+Vertex(1);y = r*sin(phi)+Vertex(2); z = (c*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2))./(1+sqrt(1-(1+k)*c^2*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2)))+Vertex(3);surf(x,z,y);set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'ZBuffer')hold on Vertex=[0 0.399 0];phi = (linspace(0,2*pi,n));r=(linspace(0,Dr,n))';x = r*cos(phi)+Vertex(1); y = r*sin(phi)+Vertex(2); z = (c*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2))./(1+sqrt(1-(1+k)*c^2*((r*cos(phi)).^2+(r*sin(phi)).^2)))+Vertex(3);surf(x,z,y)

Comment: My main problem Werner like you said is adjust the formula so that the toroids are located one higher the other in the Y axis